# Computing the inverse of linear transformations using matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse, linear-transformations

For each of the following linear transformations T, determine whether T is invertible, and compute T<sup>-1</sup> if it exists.

(a) T: P<sub>2</sub>(*R*) $\to$ P<sub>2</sub>(*R*) defined by T(*f(x)*) = *f ''(x)* + 2 *f '(x)* - *f(x)*.

> My answer:
>
> Using the standard basis of P<sub>2</sub>(*R*), $\beta$ = {1, x, x<sup>2</sup>} I got that the matrix representation of T is 
>           \begin{matrix}
>         -1 & 2 & 2 \\
>         0 & -1 & 4 \\
>         0 & 0 & -1 \\
>         \end{matrix}
>
> Taking its inverse, I got 
>           \begin{matrix}
>         -1 & -2 & -10 \\
>         0 & -1 & -4 \\
>         0 & 0 & -1 \\
>         \end{matrix}
>
> However, from here, I *don't know* how to use the inverse matrix to define T<sup>-1</sup>.

Similarly,

(b) T: **R**<sup>3</sup> $\to$ P<sub>2</sub>(*R*) defined by T(*a*, *b*, *c*) = (*a*+*b*+*c*)+(*a*-*b*+*c*)*x*+ *a* *x*<sup>2</sup>

> Matrix representation using basis of **R**<sup>3</sup>, {(1, 0, 0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)} and basis of P<sub>2</sub>(*R*), {1, x, x<sup>2</sup>}
>           \begin{matrix}
>         1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         1 & -1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 0 & 0 \\
>         \end{matrix}
>
> Taking the inverse I get 
>           \begin{matrix}
>         0 & 0 & 1 \\
>         1/2 & -1/2 & 0 \\
>         1/2 & 1/2 & -1 \\
>         \end{matrix}
>
> And again, I don't know how to use this inverse to define T<sup>-1</sup>: __________.

Similarly,

(c) T: P<sub>2</sub>(*R*) $\to$ **R**<sup>3</sup> defined by T(*f(x)*) = (*f*(-1), *f*(0), *f*(1))

> Using the same bases as in (b), I got the matrix representation
>           \begin{matrix}
>         1 & -1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 0 & 0 \\
>         1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         \end{matrix}
>
> with inverse
>           \begin{matrix}
>         0 & 1 & 0 \\
>         -1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
>         1/2 & -1 & 1/2 \\
>         \end{matrix}
>
> Again, I don't know how to use this information to define T. Please help me, especially in the last two problems where the vector spaces are different. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a question of what "matrix of a linear transformation" means.  For your third question you have
$$C^{-1}\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr c\cr}
  =\pmatrix{b\cr-\frac12a+\frac12c\cr \frac12a-b+\frac12c\cr}\ ,$$
assuming your calculated inverse is correct (I haven't checked).  Using the bases you have given in (b), this means
$$\eqalign{T^{-1}(a\color{red}{(1,0,0)}+&b\color{red}{(0,1,0)}+c\color{red}{(0,0,1)})\cr
  &=b\color{blue}{1}+\bigl(-\frac12a+\frac12c\bigr)\color{blue}{x}
    +\bigl(\frac12a-b+\frac12c\bigr)\color{blue}{x^2}\ ,\cr}\tag{$*$}$$
that is,
$$T^{-1}(a,b,c)=b+\bigl(-\frac12a+\frac12c\bigr)x
  +\bigl(\frac12a-b+\frac12c\bigr)x^2\ .$$

You can easily check that $T(T^{-1}({\bf v}))=\bf v$ and $T^{-1}(T(f))=f$.

Comment: so, what does a matrix of a linear transformation mean? and what do I plug in in the case for P_2(R) to R^3? I can't just do (a, b, c) because it is in the form ax^2 + bx + c. (second problem)

Comment: is (b) T^(-1) = (a, (1/2)c-(1/2)b, (1/2)c+(1/2)b-a)? @David

Comment: If you search "matrix of a linear transformation" on math.se you will find lots of explanations.  In (c) the inverse is from ${\Bbb R}^3$ to ${\Bbb P}_2$ which is why I did scalars times $(1,0,0),\,(0,1,1),\,(0,0,1)$ on the left hand side (red vectors in equation $(*)$) and $1,x,x^2$ on the right hand side (blue vectors).  If it was from ${\Bbb P}_2$ to ${\Bbb R}^3$ you would simply do these the other way round.